# asp.net image tag displays image only in visual studio debugging mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'd like to compile and deploy a finished image that will efficiently display the image I've set up in the following line:

```
imgtag.ImageUrl = "..\..\Images\IMG_Temp\" & "PVATmp" & Trim(CStr(mlnk)) & ".jpg"
```

This line displays the image smoothly and quickly in the designer when I debug, but not after the program is compiled and displayed on an IIS Web server instance. For one thing, the image is displayed on a postback in designer, but that condition in the deployed version cannot show the image. I have to refresh the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm closing this question, thanks. The issue I'm describing is actually more a question of why do I have to refresh. I'll post another question that's more finely detailed about what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The path the image is displayed from is relative. `..\..`Means you are moving 2 levels up from where you are now. "where you are now" likely means something different while debugging than it does when deployed.

Also, does your variable `mlnk` have a value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this:

```
imgtag.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Images/IMG_TEMP/PVATmp" + Trim(CStr(mlnk)) + ".jpg";
```

This is in case when you IMAGES folder is located in the root path

Comment: I'm closing this question, thanks. The issue I'm describing is actually more a question of why do I have to refresh. I'll post another question that's more finely detailed about what I'm seeing.